# I can't install gnome-shell and edubuntu secondary bundle for ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, gnome, edubuntu

I tryed to install Gnome-Shell and Edubuntu Secondary Bundle for ubuntu but in place of showing install it shows "Available from the 'universe' source".

Please tell how to install.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enable installs from the 'universe' source:

1. Run `software-properties-gtk` or start the *Software Sources* application from the menu
2. In the *Ubuntu Software* tab, check "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)"

Comment: Hey it's checked.

Comment: And did it work or not?

Comment: after reboot it worked

Comment: Do you mind marking it as the solution in that case?